# Trouble with eclipse.ini

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-adt

I hoping I'm not doubling this question, but I did search thoroughly.

I have adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702 downloaded and learned that I need 64 bit java which I have installed.  However, it's looking for 32 bit java.

When I download a 32 bit Eclipse application, it's fine.  Because I have the 64 bit adt already updated, I would like to use the 64 bit Eclipse found in that package.

After going through the trouble shooting found here, I have noticed that my eclipse.ini isn't looking like all the examples I've seen (showing -vm {path_to_64bit_java}\bin\javaw.exe)

https://www.dropbox.com/s/d14hu6hb6dmqdx6/Screenshot%202014-10-27%2021.43.40.png?dl=0

I would like to edit this so that eclipse will use the java 64 bit that I have installed in Program Files.

Do I need to add a line here or is there something missing from this screenshot?

Any help would be appreciated.  I'm using Windows 8.1 and I didn't have this problem the first time I installed Eclipse.

This is my .ini when opened in Notepad++

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20120913-144807
-product
com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.adtproduct
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m

I would need to insert a line after "openFile" ?
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the lines:

```
-vm
path to java
```

in the eclipse.ini to tell Eclipse where to look for Java.

These lines must come **before** the `-vmargs` line (so at the beginning of the file for example).

The `-vm` and the path must be on separate lines.

Comment: Edit your original question to add extra information

Comment: Thanks greg-449.  I fixed that issue.  Appreciated.

Comment: Adding on a new line after 'openFile' is fine.